# Spring MVC- how to resolve views?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and I am developing a dummy Bank transaction project. Upto now I have created a welcome page that links me to the page where I can perform deposit or withdraw transaction. The database and everything works fine. And, I have a table that shows the list of customers having 4 attributes(id, name, acctNo, balance). The id is linked to the next page where I want to show only the information about this customer. How can I achieve this.

The Dispatcher-Servlet.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p">      
     <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="urlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref local="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="urlMap">
            <map>              
                <entry key="/login.html">
                    <ref bean="userloginController"/>
                </entry>
            </map>          
        </property>             
    </bean>


   <!-- I tried adding this bean but noe luck, not sure where to use this id to map this bean -->
     <bean id="showindividualCustomer" class="com.showCustomerController">s
        <property name="successView"> <value>ViewCustomer</value></property>
     </bean>

     <bean id="userloginController" class="com.UserLoginFormController">
        <property name="sessionForm"><value>false</value></property>
        <property name="commandName"><value>userLogin</value></property>
        <property name="commandClass"><value>com.UserLogin</value></property>
        <property name="formView"><value>userLogin</value></property>
        <property name="successView"><value>showCustomer</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="hl"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>      
</beans>
```

And the controller for bean=showindividualcustomer is:

```
public class showCustomerController extends SimpleFormController{

    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object obj) throws ServletException{

        return new ModelAndView("ViewCustomer");//name of the jsp page inside WEB-INF/jsp
    }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually recommend taking full advantage of spring 3, looking at your code I assume you're looking at a spring 2 tutorial.

Using spring 2.5.6 or spring 3.* you could just do:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/customer/{id}")
    public String showCustomerInformation(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest request){
        //your logic to get the customer information and pass it on
        return "customerInformation";
    }
```

Some references:
http://tech-read.com/2011/10/31/spring-3-mvc-annotations/
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

edit:
Change your method signature to:

```
onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, Object command) throws ServletException
```

And just use:

```
request.getParameter("id")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but could you please provide me the solution in Spring 2.x